# Sorting a collection of tuples using merge rearrangements

Tags: optimization, sorting, np-hard, combinatorics

Given a collection of tuples $X=\{(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n)\}$, where elements
$x_i, y_i \in R_{\geq 0}$ are non-negative real values. The collection $X$ is
sorted if $x_i \leq x_{i+1}$ and $y_i \leq y_{i+1}$ for all $i \in [n-1]$. Sorting $X$ is not
always possible for instance if the given input has two tuples $(x_i,y_i), (x_j,y_j)$ such that $x_i > x_j $ and $y_i < y_j$ for some $i \neq j$. So we want to merge tuples in $X$ so that the resulting collection is sorted and the merge operation $\phi(i,j,k)$ is defined as

$$\phi(i,j,k) := \Big\{\text{delete}~(x_i,y_i), (x_j,y_j)~\text{from}~X~\text{and insert}~\big(\frac{x_i+x_j}{2}, \frac{y_i+y_j}{2}\big)~\text{at position}~k\big\}$$

The problem always has an obvious solution with $(n-1)$ merge operations i.e, merging
everything to a single tuple is always feasible. But we would like to find
the **minimum number of merge operations** required to sort the collection.

Even though we suspect that finding the minimum number of merge operations is
NP-hard, we do not have a hardness proof to support the claim.
The problem looks like something which might have been already studied in the
literature. If you are aware of any related or similar problems please guide us to relevant results. Any clues for hardness or algorithmic results are helpful.

**Example:** Given $X=\{(1,4),(2,2),(3,2),(4,1)\}$ with two merge operations i.e, $\phi(1,4,3)$ followed by $\phi(2,3,2)$ we can obtain $\{(2.5,2),(2.5,2.5)\}$, which is sorted.

$$\{(1,4),(2,2),(3,2),(4,1)\} \xrightarrow[]{\phi(1,4,3)} \{(2,2),(3,2),(2.5,2.5)\}$$
$$\{(2,2),(3,2),(2.5,2.5)\} \xrightarrow[]{\phi(2,3,2)} \{(2,2),(2.5,2.25)\}$$

**Note-1:** $\phi(i,i,k)$ is a valid operation.

**Note-2:** While inserting an element at some index $\ell$, the index of tuples at positions $\{\ell,\dots,n\}$ are incremented by $1$, i.e, no element in the collection is deleted while inserting.

**Note-3:** If the merge operation is restricted to operations of the form $\phi(i,i+1,i)$ and insert the resulting element at position $i$, then the minimum number of operations can be found in polynomial time using a dynamic programming algorithm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder how you can solve $\phi(i, i+1, i)$ using dynamic programming. I guess you try to solve some problem on every segment (a la matrix chain multiplication problem), but the problem is that depending on the order you get different resulting tuple.

Comment: Is $\phi(i, i, k)$ a valid operation?

Comment: @Gribouillis yes you can allow rearrangement operations $\phi(i,i,k)$. However, I think the optimal solution will avoid making such rearrangements.

Comment: I'm confused by allowing us to choose $k$.  Does that mean we can overwrite and delete some other existing element of $X$?  For instance, is $\phi(10,11,5)$ a legal operation?  I suspect that there should be no $k$, and you are allowed to delete the pairs at $i,j$ and then append/insert the new pair.

Comment: How can you say that the optimal will avoid $\phi(i, i, k) $? What about $X=\{(2,2),(1,2)\} $? Is merge rearrange the only allowed operation? If not then @D.W. might be right that $k$ is not needed in $\phi() $

Comment: @D.W. You are right. We are allowed to delete the pairs at position $i,j$ and insert the new pair at any position in the array. I will update the problem statement.

Comment: I think $\phi(i, j)$ without $k$ is not well defined because it defines different changes of state depending on where the new pair is inserted. Given the initial state and the sequence of $\phi(i, j)$, it is impossible to predict the final state. As if in a chess game we said move a pawn, then a pawn, then a knight, etc without the destination square.

Comment: The order of the integers in the collection doesn't seem to matter.  I think you should specify the collection as a set (not list), and have the $\phi$ operation delete two pair and inserts another pair.

Answer (score 0):

A crude estimate is that the worst number of merges is greater or equal to $\frac{n-1}{4}$. For this, consider the set
\begin{equation}
X=\{(0,1),\ldots,(0,m)\}\cup\{(1, 0),\ldots,(m, 0)\}
\end{equation}
where $m = \lfloor n/2\rfloor$. None of the points of the first list is comparable to any of the points of the second list. It means that if one of the points is untouched by the merging operations, then all the points of the other list must be touched by at least one merge operation. As each merge operation involves two points, it means that there are at least $\lceil m/2 \rceil$ merge operations. But $\lceil \lfloor n/2\rfloor /2\rceil\ge \frac{n-1}{4}$.

One can even reach a lower bound of $\frac{n-1}{2}$ by considering a set
\begin{equation}
X = \{(a_1, -a_1), \ldots, (a_n, -a_n)\}
\end{equation}
where $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are distinct real numbers. Pairs of points in $X$ are never comparable, which means that $n-1$ of them must take part in a merge operation. Hence there are at least $\frac{n-1}{2}$ merge operations.

If we add more conditions on the $a_k$ s, for example assuming that they are independent over ${\mathbb Q}$, we have an exemple where $n-1$ merge operations are actually necessary because the points $(x, y)$ generated by the merge operations will always have the form $(x, -x)$ and they will always be distinct. They will never become comparable and the algorithm can stop only when the cardinality of $X$ is $1$, that is to say after $n-1$ operations.